# Could not find “store” in either the context or props of “Connect(App)” in Jest/React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to run my first jest test but it seems like there's an issue with the way my react files are set up:

app_test:

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const app = shallow(<App />);
});
```

app.js

```
class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchUserAccountInfo();
  }

  render() {
    return <MainRoutes auth={this.props.loggedIn} />;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    loggedIn: state.loggedIn.userLoggedIn,
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchUserAccountInfo }
)(App);
```

index.js (embeds App.s)

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
const bugsnagClient = bugsnag({...//bugsnag stuff})

bugsnagClient.use(bugsnagReact, React);
const ErrorBoundary = bugsnagClient.getPlugin("react");

const RootApp = () => (
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App id={token} />
    </Provider>
  </ErrorBoundary>,
);

ReactDOM.render(<RootApp />, document.getElementById('.app'));
```

They say i have an issue with shallow rendering "App"

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".
```

[image]

I'm not sure what else I need to pass through App or if I need to move the Provider down?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to import a connected component. If you only want to test the component I would recommend to `export` your **non-connected** class alongside with `connected` one and import it instead. This way you don't need to worry about store and context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JestJS -> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Portfolio)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813111/jestjs-invariant-violation-could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-p)

Answer (score 2):

The error log clearly states here that you need to provide a store to your  component. To do so, you need to mock your store beforehand, and then give it to the `<Provider />` component, containing the `<App />` as child. Your file should look like this :

```js
/* app_test */

import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './App';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const store = mockStore({}); // Instead of {}, you can give your initial store
  shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>   // Provides the store to your App
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
});
```

This piece of code should do the trick !

For more info, you can check this page: https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests